# VirtualBox Ubuntu server guest: serving of symfony app ends up with: attempt denied by server configuration

Tags: server, permissions, virtualbox, php, apache2.4

I'm running Ubuntu Server using VirtualBox to develop Symfony app.
I've set up shared folder, changed apache default folder `/var/www/html` to 
`/media/sf_apache_shared` which is shared folder, for convenient development.

The default apache's `index.html` file, denoting that apache is set up correctly, works fine. The problematic moment comes into play, once I try to run Symfony app.

If I try to create default Symfony app, I get the following result:

[image]

Although I can create Symfony app using the same way, but outside of that folder, for example inside of `/var/www/html`.

I've checked the permission of `sf_apache_shared` folder with the result of `770`, using the following command:

```
stat -c %a directory
```

But even aside from that fact, I manually copied Symfony app project to `sf_apache_shared` and tried to access that project, from the windows host, using Chrome.
The result apache's logs are:

```
client denied by server configuration: /media/sf_apache_shared/my_project_name/app/
client denied by server configuration: /media/sf_apache_shared/my_project_name/src/
```

Here is my server configuration:

[image]

Comment: Not sure about the app but I doubt it could be a permission error since the share originates from Windows to the VM. What's the output of `ls -l /media/`?

Comment: Here is the output: https://s18.postimg.org/f1pkswuxl/image.png

Comment: it sure seems like a permission issue to me.. just out of curiosity, would you try `sudo simfony new test_project` and see whether it works? The picture you have commented says root is the owner, vboxsf is the group and everyone else doesn't have any rights which blindly put apache user who's `www-data` in no control.

Comment: I logged in as a simple, not root user, and the funny fact is - I can't even go inside `sf_apache_shared` folder - Permission denied.

Comment: Well of course, they are the usual permissions of a shared folder within the VM from host. Can you try `usermod -aG vboxsf your_username` within your VM and then try to install or `cd` into the folder? should probably work! Let me know, I will further expand it as an answer.

Comment: as a root user I entered `usermod -aG vboxsf my_username`, but still unable to `cd` into that folder as `my_username` user.